How hot does engine oil need to get to "burn off" water?
Many websites quote 100C as the temperature oil needs to reach to "boil off" water accumulating from combustion byproducts. I have a lot of trouble believing that number is anything other than a myth driven by uninformed people who confuse "evaporation" with "boiling off".
However, I can't find a reference for what temperature (vs. time) is actually necessary to eliminate the water (a known source of engine component corrosion over time) which accumulates as the engine warms up.
Even water with heavy solute concentrations does not need high temperatures to fully evaporate at 1atm. So I know it's not 100C, but what do I need to take into consideration to find a real temperature? Obviously piston-ring blow-by is a major factor, but I don't have much of a sense as to whether oil is hydrophilic or hydrophobic for the low levels of moisture contamination in question.

I don't think this q. is clear enough. What you're talking about can be perhaps be considered an example of distillation, and you seem to underestimate its complexity.

Net evaporation would be the same as boiling, if water vapor partial pressure above oil surface was atmospheric pressure. In case it's lower, look up the temperature corresponding to equilibrium vapor pressure from pressure-temperature diagram of water. Oil is hydrophobic. Knowing the time dependence of evaporation requires better understanding of the engine, which I don't have.

@Mithoron happy to improve the question, although I'm not sure that I need a simple answer. A complex one will do. And the thought that this might be a distillation problem is a neat one! In the end, what I'm after is more insight than I seem to get from the links I follow where people cite random values as gospel, despite having no science or understanding behind them. Hopefully there's an opportunity here to get a response which pushes back the darkness ever so slightly.

Well, if you have so tiny amount of H2O that it's gonna actually dissolve in oil, I don't think it's gonna just evaporate, even getting over 100C may not be enough. That's likely one of the reasons why it's an issue at all.

Engine oil is not just oil, but contains many inorganic, hydrophylic compounds that might absorb water. You'd have to experiment to define that time vs. temp curve.
